# Using .attr() with .get() Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store an array of objects in an array by going through each paragraph element in a `div` container with the .`get()` method.  I try to access the attribute with .`attr()` but it doesn't seem to work.  How would I modify this code in order to be able to access the 'id' attribute of each message?

```
        var messages = $("#message_container p").get();
        var idstest = [];

        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
            idstest.push(messages[i].attr("id"));
        }
```

I think it has to do with some fundamental incompatibility with .`get()` and .`attr()`.  When I 'alert' the objects provided by .`get()` I get `[object HTML---]`.  I'm assuming that is not the form necessary in order to use .`attr`?

Comment: Can you post more of your code using something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: doesn't ` $("#message_container p")` return an array of the elements?

Comment: @chustar It returns a jquery object which contains a set of elements.  Not strictly an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get` will give you the DOM element.  These are NOT jquery objects so you can't use `attr` on them.  There's no reason to use `get` at all here.

```
    var messages = $("#message_container p");
    var idstest = [];

    messages.each(function(){
        idstest.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujdeH/

EDIT:  You also can't use `int`.

If for some reason you did want to use `get` to get the raw DOM elements, you would then just use `.id`:

http://jsfiddle.net/ujdeH/1/

```
var messages = $("#message_container p").get();
var idstest = [];

for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    idstest.push(messages[i].id);
}
```

Comment: You don't have to create a jquery object and use attr() to get the ID, 'this' in the callback is the current DOM element: `idtest.push(this.id);`

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't realize it had to be in jquery object form !

Comment: @DidierG. Good point.  If the only thing you intend to do with the elements is to grab their ID, it would be more efficient to just grab it directly from the DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

try instead:

```
var idstest = [];


 $("#message_container p").each(function(i){

idstest.push($(this).attr("id"));


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add the `$.map` shortcut: http://jsfiddle.net/UuWq3/.

```
var idstest = $.map(messages, function(elem) {
    return $(elem).attr("id");
});
```

`$.map` returns a new array based on the original array (or jQuery object). The array returned is constructed with the function you pass (in this case, `messages` is transformed by the function such that each element is replaced with it's ID).

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the object in jQuery container:

```
$(messages[i]).attr("id")
```

Comment: This works but is not the most efficient solution: 1. `$("#message_container p")` gets a jquery object; 2. `.get()` extracts all DOM element; 3. `$(messages[i])` make a new jquery object again

Comment: @DidierG. You are definitely right. Actually I was thinking to write about removing the "get()", but I thought I'd stick to why the `attr()` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need for jQuery here, this pure JavaScript will work just fine on all browsers:

```
var idstest = [];
var container = document.getElementById("message_container");
if (container) {
    var messages = container.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        idstest.push(messages[i].id);
    }
}
```

jQuery is all good and powerful, but if you can achieve the same task with short/easy enough pure JS then why not?

This said, if all your existing code is jQuery then you might be better off sticking with it (using the code from other correct answers here) just for sake of consistency and readability.

Comment: Interesting. I definitely will keep this in mind for future code.